# Show object tag content from a certain position

Tags: javascript, html, object-tag

I have an object tag that shows another website, now I want to show the content of the object from a certain position of the scroll, I tried with javascript but found nothing working. What do you suggest to do?

that is the HTML:

```
<object class="boxmeteo" id="bmeteo" type="text/html" data="https://www.3bmeteo.com/meteo/roma" >
```

JS:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("bmeteo").scroll(0,150);
</script>
```

Comment: object tag what is? a node element?

Comment: is something like that: `<object id="myobject" type="text/html" data="http://anotherwebsite.com"></object>`

Comment: Can you elaborate the part - show the content of object (i assume the inner HTML) from a certain scroll position. Do you mean displaying the inner HTML when the document scroll is at some specific value?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I meant that I want to show the inner html from a certain point of itself, not from the top of the anotherwebsite page

Comment: Show some source code please. Show what you have tried or at the very least the source html.

Comment: Share the code which you have used and give the expected output sketch.

Comment: Use `data="http://anotherwebsite.com#divid"`

Comment: That should work, and how can I hide something of the original page, like ads or kinda?